# Is there a way in Django CBV post function to add information to context

Tags: django

I've got the following code

```
class MusicFileUploadView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "music_file_upload.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'csv-file' in request.FILES.keys():
            csv_file = request.FILES['csv-file']
            upload = FileUpload(csv_file=csv_file)
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                upload.user_uploaded = request.user
            response = upload.save()
            if response['error']:
                #add error to context
                pass
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

where in the post section I save an upload file and parse it, incase of an error I want to include the message in the context so I can display it on the same page.

Is there a way to include that in the post function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `get_context_data()` method.

`get_context_data()` essentially takes the `**kwargs` and returns them as a dictionary with any `extra_context` from your view class.

So when you call the parent class `post()` or `get()` you will need to include your updated context in the **kwargs.

```py
class MusicFileUploadView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the context
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Modify the context here.

        # Pass the updated context to the parent class
        return super().get(request, *args, **context)
```